# Google Docs App Script create dropdown in table cell

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to insert a dropdown in the google docs table cell but cannot find anything related to doing it, is it possible?

```
var dropdownCell = tableRow.appendTableCell('')
var rule = document.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(['Yes', 'No'], false).build();
cell.setDataValidation(rule);
```

Comment: About `insert a dropdown in the google docs table cell` and your showing script, I understood that you wanted to try to achieve this using Google Apps Script. I think that the dropdown list at Google Documents is one of the smart chips. Unfortunately, in the current stage, the smart chips cannot be managed by Google Apps Script. But, I believe that this might be resolved in the future update. So, now, how about reporting this to the Google issue tracker as a future request? But, if I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

if unable to find any solutions, I would try reverse engineer

1. Manually create a file, add a Table and some dropdown lists
2. Extract Text and Object as described in this code https://developers.google.com/docs/api/samples/extract-text

Maybe I will try it next week or the following week, I will keep you posted if I try. If you try this approach